# Почему при конвертировании файла htaccess в nginx формат nginx не запускается и бьет ошибку?

Tags: apache, nginx

Есть следующий файл

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?act=$1
Options -Indexes
```

Я конвертировал его для конфига nginx и получил следующее

```
autoindex off;

    location / {
      if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?act=$1;
      }
    }
```

При добавлении в конфиг того что получилось у меня не заводится нгинкс, как лечить?

Comment: 1. «конвертирование» — это абсурд. 2. https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: Каким конфигом мне достичь нужного результата? С нгинксом первый раз работаю.